# To describe an invariant trivector in dimension 8 geometrically

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory

$\newcommand\Alt{\bigwedge\nolimits}$Let $G=\operatorname{SL}(2,\Bbb C)$, and let $R$ denote the natural 2-dimensional representation of $G$ in ${\Bbb C}^2$.
For an integer $p\ge 0$, write $R_p=S^p R$; then $R_1=R$ and  $\dim R_p=p+1$.

Using Table 5 in the book of Onishchik and Vinberg, I computed that the representation
$$ R_2\otimes\Alt^2 R_4 $$
contains the trivial representation with multiplicity one.
I used the table as a black box.

> **Question.** Let $V\subset  R_2\otimes\Alt^2 R_4$ denote the corresponding one-dimensional subspace.
> How can one describe $V$ as a subspace ***geometrically***?

**Motivation:** I want to consider a $\operatorname{PGL}(2,k)$-fixed trivector
$$v\in V\subset R_2\otimes\Alt^2 R_4\subset \Alt^3(R_2\oplus R_4)$$
of  the 8-dimensional vector space $W=R_2\oplus R_4$
over a field $k$ of characteristic 0,
and then to twist all this using a Galois-cocycle of $\operatorname{PGL}(2,k)$. For this end I need a geometric description of $V$.

Feel free to add/edit tags!

Comment: Did you intend to start with $\mathbb C$, and switch to $k$?  Also, if $k$ is not algebraically closed, is it clear that the $\operatorname{SL}(2, k)$-fixed vectors are $\operatorname{PGL}(2, k)$-fixed?  (I guess a geometric description might make it clear!)

Comment: @LSpice as the representation is algebraic, yes it's clear since $k$ is infinite and hence $\mathrm{SL}(2,k)$ is Zariski-dense.

Comment: @YCor, good point, but I don't think that there's any hypothesis stated on $k$.

Comment: @LSpice ah I assumed it's a subfield of $\mathbf{C}$, but anyway Mikhail will eventually clarify.

Comment: Seeing 8 and 3 here makes me wonder whether there's some way to find a $G = \operatorname{SL}_2$ inside $\tilde G = \operatorname{Spin}_8$ so that the spinor representation of $\tilde G$ becomes the $R_2 \oplus R_4$ representation of $G$, and then use triality somehow.

Comment: [Specifically](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377349/to-describe-an-invariant-trivector-in-dimension-8-geometrically#comment957190_377349), there's a trilinear form on the octonions whose fixer is the compact $\mathsf G_2$, so maybe we can complexify and find an appropriate $\operatorname{SL}_2$ inside $\mathsf G_2$.

Comment: @LSpice:  There is a construction of octonions as pairs $(s,S)$ where $s$ is a scalar and $S$ is a binary sextic. Multiplication is done in an $SL_2$ invariant way using the third transvectant (to produce another sextic) and the sixth transvectant (to produce a scalar). See this article by Dixmier https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/crll/1984/346/article-p110.xml

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, [thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377349#comment957216_377349)!  Unfortunately I realised that looking at the vector representation restricted to $\mathsf G_2$ is no good and trying to find a copy of $R_2 \oplus R_4$ is no good, because it has a fixed vector, but maybe still inside $\operatorname{Spin}_8$?  (I'm not up enough on my invariant language to see if this is consistent with your hint.)\\Name of the Dixmier article: [Certaines algèbres non associatives simples définies par la transvection des formes binaires](https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1984.346.110).

Comment: Not sure about if $G_2$ helps for the OP's question. But as far a connection between $G_2$ and $SL_2$, Dixmier's article is definitely relevant.

Comment: Wouldn’t be helpful to observe that both $R_2$ and $R_4$ are not faithful in the same manner? Ī̲ mean that −1 lies in their kernel, hence both, in fact, represent PSL(2)—for *k* = ℂ known in physics as the special orthochronous Lorentz group—and all spaces mentioned here are endowed with a PSL(2) representation, not merely SL(2).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's another very nice (but still algebraic) interpretation that explains some of the geometry:  Recall that $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ has a $2$-to-$1$ representation into $\operatorname{SL}(3,\mathbb{C})$ so that the Lie algebra splits as
$$
{\frak{sl}}(3,\mathbb{C}) = {\frak{sl}}(2,\mathbb{C})\oplus {\frak{m}}
$$
where ${\frak{m}}$ is the ($5$-dimensional) orthogonal complement of ${\frak{sl}}(2,\mathbb{C})$ using the Killing form of ${\frak{sl}}(3,\mathbb{C})$.   Note that ${\frak{m}}$ is an irreducible ${\frak{sl}}(2,\mathbb{C})$-module, and that every element $x\in {\frak{sl}}(3,\mathbb{C})$ can be written uniquely as $x = x_0 + x_1$ with $x_0\in {\frak{sl}}(2,\mathbb{C})$ and $x_1\in{\frak{m}}$.  Note also that $[{\frak{m}},{\frak{m}}]= {\frak{sl}}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

This defines the desired pairing ${\frak{sl}}(2,\mathbb{C})\times \bigwedge\nolimits^2({\frak{m}})\to\mathbb{C}$:  Send $(x_0,y_1,z_1)$ to $\operatorname{tr}(x_0[y_1,z_1])$.  Of course, this makes the $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$-invariance of the pairing obvious.

Comment: The 2-to-1 representation is just the adjoint representation, right?

Comment: @LSpice:  Yes, of course.  There's really only one (up to conjugacy).  It's a little bit easier to see how everything works if you represent the image as ${\frak{so}}(3,\mathbb{C})\subset{\frak{sl}}(3,\mathbb{C})$, for then ${\frak{so}}(3,\mathbb{C})$ is the skew-symmetric matrices while $\frak{m}$ is the traceless symmetric matrices.  This makes it clear that $[{\frak{m}},{\frak{m}}] = \mathfrak{so}(3,\mathbb{C})$ and shows exactly how everything works as an $\mathfrak{so}(3,\mathbb{C})$ representation.

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 11):

For a purely geometric construction, see further below, after the following algebraic considerations.

There is a Wronskian isomorphism which as a particular case says that the second exterior power of $R_4$ is isometric to the second symmetric power of $R_3$. So the invariant in question is $I(Q,C)$, a joint invariant in a binary quadratic $Q$ and a binary cubic $C$, which is linear in $Q$ and quadratic in $C$. This is indeed unique up to scale and is given in classical symbolic notation (see, e.g., Grace and Young) by
$$
(ab)(ac)(bc)^2
$$
where $Q=a_{x}^{2}$ and $C=b_{x}^{3}=c_{x}^{3}$.

Another construction is to start from the binary discriminant, and polarize it to get a bilinear form (the unique invariant one on $R_2$), and apply this bilinear form to $Q$ and the Hessian of $C$.

If one does not want to use the Wronskian isomorphism then the invariant would be $J(Q,F_1,F_2)$, trilinear in the quadratic $Q$ and the two binary quartics $F_1,F_2$. It would satisy the antisymmetry $J(Q,F_2,F_1)=-J(Q,F_1,F_2)$ and would be given in symbolic form by
$$
(ab)(ac)(bc)^3
$$
where now $Q=a_{x}^{2}$, $F_1=b_{x}^{4}$, and $F_2=c_{x}^{4}$.

---

**Geometric construction:**

Consider $\mathbb{P}^1$ embedded by Veronese as a conic $\mathscr{C}$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$. A binary quadratic $Q$ corresponds to a point in $\mathbb{P}^2$.
A binary cubic $C$ corresponds to a divisor or an unordered collection of three points $\{P_1,P_2,P_3\}$ on $\mathscr{C}$. Let $T_1, T_2, T_3$ be the tangents to the conic at $P_1,P_2,P_3$. Consider the points of intersection $T_1\cap P_2P_3$, $T_2\cap P_1P_3$, $T_3\cap P_1P_2$. They are aligned and thus define a line $L$. The vanishing of the invariant $I(Q,C)$ detects the situation where the point $Q$ is on the line $L$. I don't remember if the collinearity result I mentioned has a name, but it is a degenerate case of Pascal's Theorem.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to read Grace and Young, the book published in 1903....

Comment: No pbm. For more geometry, it's probably possible to express the vanishing of $I(Q,C)$ as a special configuration of three points on a conic (the roots of the cubic) in the projective plane and a point in the plane corresponding to Q.

Comment: I had never heard of Wronskian isomorphisms, and the first Google result was [another answer of yours](https://mathoverflow.net/a/184827).  Are the papers by you and Chipalkatti, [On Hilbert covariants](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4761) and [On the Wronskian combinants of binary forms](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507488), referenced there the best place to learn about this?

Comment: Of course....;)